# Rails .js render html in modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm passing the following as a parameter to a modal:

```
"<iframe width="350" height="197" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/jsExp2ebB4s?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

Then, I try to render it dynamically in a modal...in my show.js....

$("#modalpostvid").html("params[:vid]")

But it loads text (i.e. loads it as a string) instead of the embedded video.

How can I make it so that the video embeds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("#modalpostvid").html("<%= escape_javascript params[:vid].html_safe %>")
```

Comment: still getting the string...not embedding

Comment: try calling `html_safe` on the params.

Comment: perfect.  thank you.  will accept your answer in 4 mins(when allowed).